# when folder script is run it overrides the old hyperlinks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

the below script is used to create folders that are used for projects,

the problem is when the script is run a second time it gets rid of the previously created hyperlinks that was created the first time is was used but the folders still remain in the parent folder

the folders still exist by the cell goes from =HYPERLINK("insert folder link", "J10447") to =HYPERLINK("undefined", "J10447")

```
function creatFolder() {
  const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder id");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Detailing');
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  range.getValues().forEach(function (row, index) {
    // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
    if(row[0]) {
      var newLink = getLinkForFolderName_(parent, row[0]);
      // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
      range.offset(index, 0, 1).setFormula(
        "HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + row[0] + "\")"
      );
    }
  });
}



function getLinkForFolderName_(root, name) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }
  else {
  folder = root.createFolder(name);
  ["Quotes", "Construction dwg's", "Window Schedule", "Data File", "Delivery Photos"].forEach(function(e) {
    folder.createFolder(e);
  });
    return folder.getUrl();
}
}
```

Comment: Use a status column to let you now the hyperlink has already been created

Comment: Have you tried checking the formula on the cell first using [`getFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula) before calling `getLinkForFolderName_`? This way, you can skip setting the formula again if your existing formula is already fine.

Answer (score 1):

I made a temp fix to the issue based on Cooper's comment, so now the the hyperlink is created in column A then it is moved to column B which then causes column A to be erased

below is the updated script in case someone wants to use it, I will be trying to figure out a better way and will post it when that happens

```
function creatFoder() {
  const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder id");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Detailing');
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  range.getValues().forEach(function (row, index) {
    // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
    if(row[0]) {
      var newLink = getLinkForFolderName_(parent, row[0]);
      // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
      range.offset(index, 1, 1).setFormula(
        "HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + row[0] + "\")"
      );
    }
  });
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").clear();
}



function getLinkForFolderName_(root, name) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }
  else {
  folder = root.createFolder(name);
  ["Quotes", "Construction dwg's", "Window Schedule", "Data File", "Delivery Photos"].forEach(function(e) {
    folder.createFolder(e);
  });
    return folder.getUrl();
}
}
```